# MySQL IN() for two value/array?

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble finding a better way to search MySQL for a pair of values in a table. I have the value pairs in an array, and would like to duplicate the IN() function, but for more than 1 value.

For example purposed; I have the following 3 pairs:

```
foo,1
boo,2
goo,3
```

The current solution puts me at:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE 
(column1 = 'foo' AND column2 = 1) OR
(column1 = 'boo' AND column2 = 2) OR
(column1 = 'goo' AND column2 = 3);
```

I'd like to think there's a more "sexy" solution seeing that I could have as many as a hundred pairs and having that may ORs kind of makes me nauseous.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    foo
WHERE   (column1, column2) IN (('foo', 1), ('bar', 2))
```

This syntax may be confusing, and it may be more readable to replace it with:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    foo
WHERE   ROW(column1, column2) IN (ROW('foo', 1), ROW('bar', 2))
```

I'm used to the former one, though :)

Comment: That works great! Seems so obvious now that you've I've seen it.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I didn't not know.. Thanks mate!

Comment: I had an inkling that something like this might exist but never thought it would be so easy.  This is going to be helpful in a number of contexts.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you can get your values into a temp table (you only need the two columns) easily and quickly, you can just INNER JOIN your way there.  If not, you'll have to use @Quassnoi version.

Answer (score 0):

Great answers from @Quassnoi and @KM !!!

Also, you can get pairs duplicates and select them for post-processing:

```
SELECT *
FROM `foo`
WHERE (`id_obj` , `Foo_obj`)
IN (
  SELECT `id_obj` , `Foo_obj`
  FROM `foo`
  GROUP BY `id_obj` , `Foo_obj`
  HAVING count(*) > 1
)
```