# MultiColumn where IN in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am running a query like this -

```
UPDATE table                                                                                                                                                           
SET eligible=1                                                                                                                                                                                             
where (name, age) in [["john",29],["mark",28],["jim",20]]
```

table structure is like this

```
name      age     eligible
mark       28      null
john       29      null
Max        20      null
```

But mysql throws the wrong syntax error, can anyone confirm that this is allowed in mysql?

Comment: Try to look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793784/mysql-in-for-two-value-array). I think this answer suits you.

Comment: @MatveiNazaruk Yeah, It does, but the array I am using is dynamic, how will I convert [] to ()

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY id LIMIT 10;
+----+-------+--------+
| id | type  | count  |
+----+-------+--------+
|  1 | green |      4 |
|  2 | blue  |      3 |
|  3 | blue  | 443792 |
|  4 | green | 455353 |
|  5 | blue  | 445389 |
|  6 | blue  | 360885 |
|  7 | green | 468258 |
|  8 | red   | 258636 |
|  9 | blue  | 388405 |
| 10 | green | 166117 |
+----+-------+--------+

 SELECT * 
   FROM my_table 
  WHERE (type,count) IN (('red',1000),('green',2000),('blue',3000)) ORDER BY id LIMIT 100
    -> ;
+--------+-------+-------+
| id     | type  | count |
+--------+-------+-------+
| 137339 | blue  |  3000 |
| 339554 | red   |  1000 |
| 947445 | green |  2000 |
+--------+-------+-------+
```

Note that MySQL can have problems utilising indexes when using this method. For that reason, it can prove more efficient to write the query out 'long-hand'.

Comment: the array is gettting created dynamically, is there any way to convert [["john",29],["mark",28],["jim",20]] to (("john",29), ("mark",28), ("jim",20))

Comment: Yes. Amend the algorithm that creates the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on an older version of MySQL, or an alternative way is to separate out the where statements:

```
UPDATE table                                                                                                                                                           
SET eligible=1                                                                                                                                                                                             
WHERE
(name = "john" AND age = 29) OR
(name = "mark" AND age = 28) OR
(name = "jim" AND age = 20)
```

Comment: Interesting, when did mysql support multi-column where in's?

Comment: For as long as I can remember, so at least since 5.1 I guess.